# Why DD output image file is larger than the source partition/runs out of space while copying partition to a file

Tags: filesystems, disk-space, dd, ext

DD output image file is larger than the source partition and DD runs out of space on the target partition(where the image is created) despite it being  larger than the source partition.

I am trying to copy a partition to a file on another partition on the same disk. The target partition is slightly larger than the input partition. Both are `ext3` partitions.

Running from OpenSuse-Rescue LIVE CD. Yast shows the input partition (`sdb1`) is 62.5 GiB and the output one `sdb2` is 62.85 GiB.

Thunar shows the input `sdb1` is 65.9 GB and the output one `sdb2` is 66.2 GB, while the output `dd` image file is being also 66.2 so obviously maxing out `sdb2`.

Here is the console:

(`sdb1` was unmounted, tried `dd` few times)

```
linux:# dd if=/dev/sdb1 of=RR.image bs=4096

dd: error writing ‘RR.image’: No space left on device
16156459+0 records in
16156458+0 records out
66176851968 bytes (66 GB) copied, 2648.89 s, 25.0 MB/s
```

---

Additional info by request:

And again : I am seeing the difference in the source partition size `sdb1` and the DD image file `RR.image` it created from it. That file resides on `sdb2`.

---

There is still something unclear here: I am RUNNING DD AS ROOT, so that reserved space is available to write into, correct? The target `sdb2` is 62.85 GiB while the total bytes for the image as you said are about 61.63 GiB. Here is also the output of `df` and `POSIXLY_CORRECT=1 df` commands:

The system now is system-rescue-cd

```
root@sysresccd /root % df

Filesystem 1K-blocks Used Available Use% Mounted on
…
/dev/sdb1 64376668 7086884 56241208 12% /media/Data1
/dev/sdb2 64742212 64742212 0 100% /media/Data2
/dev/sdb3 5236728 4785720 451008 92% /usr/local

root@sysresccd /root % POSIXLY_CORRECT=1 df /dev/sdb1 
Filesystem     512B-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sdb1        128753336 14173768 112482416  12% /media/Data1

root@sysresccd /root % POSIXLY_CORRECT=1 df /dev/sdb2    
Filesystem     512B-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sdb2        129484424 129484424         0 100% /media/Data2
```

The numbers are exactly the same as in simple `df` if we divide it by 2. 1024b/512b=2 is the divisor.

1. `sdb1` is smaller than `sdb2`. The 100 percent usage on `sdb2` now is because of the DD image file that filled the partition up. It has to be the only file on it now.
2. The image file itself is 66,176,851,968 bytes as of DD (at run time) and Thunar reports. Divided by 1024 bytes we get 64625832 K-blocks correct? So it is still smaller than `df` reported for `sdb2` by more than 116380K and it is LARGER THAN THE `sdb1` (THE SOURCE), but it maxes out the partition `sdb2`.

The question is: what is in there to take that space on `sdb2`?

---

But most important and interesting is:

Why is the target file larger than the source partition that `dd` created it from? Which means to me: I can't write it back.

`sdb1` (64376668K) < `RR.image` (64625832K)

And

`sdb1` (64376668 1K-blocks) < `RR.image` (64625832 1K-blocks) < `sdb2` (64742212 1K-blocks)

(I hope things were calculated right…)

Now I checked the blocks that are rerserved for ROOT. I found this command to execute:

```
root@sysresccd /root % dumpe2fs -h /dev/sdb1 2> /dev/null | awk -F ':' '{ if($1 == "Reserved block count") { rescnt=$2 } } { if($1 == "Block count") { blkcnt=$2 } } END { print "Reserved blocks: "(rescnt/blkcnt)*100"%" }'

Reserved blocks: 1.6%

root@sysresccd /root % dumpe2fs -h /dev/sdb2 2> /dev/null | awk -F ':' '{ if($1 == "Reserved block count") { rescnt=$2 } } { if($1 == "Block count") { blkcnt=$2 } } END { print "Reserved blocks: "(rescnt/blkcnt)*100"%" }'

Reserved blocks: 1.59999%
```

So the percentage reserved for ROOT is also the same on both partitions in case that matters.

---

Here is the output for `gdisk`:

```
root@sysresccd /root % gdisk -l /dev/sdb

GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 1.0.1

Partition table scan:
  MBR: MBR only
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: not present


***************************************************************
Found invalid GPT and valid MBR; converting MBR to GPT format
in memory. 
***************************************************************

Disk /dev/sdb: 312581808 sectors, 149.0 GiB
Logical sector size: 512 bytes
Disk identifier (GUID): DCF8AFC4-11CA-46C5-AB7A-4818336EBCA3
Partition table holds up to 128 entries
First usable sector is 34, last usable sector is 312581774
Partitions will be aligned on 2048-sector boundaries
Total free space is 7789 sectors (3.8 MiB)

Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
   1            2048       131074047   62.5 GiB    8300  Linux filesystem
   2       131074048       262889471   62.9 GiB    8300  Linux filesystem
   3       302086144       312580095   5.0 GiB     0700  Microsoft basic data
   5       262891520       293771263   14.7 GiB    8300  Linux filesystem
   6       293773312       302086143   4.0 GiB     8200  Linux swap
```

So what is the real size of `sdb1` then?

Isn't `sdb2` (N2) larger than `sdb1` (N1)? So  WHY the image file GROWS LARGER than `sdb2` (N2)? If I turn off the space reserved for root on `sdb2`, shall it fit there then?

Comment: If my answer doesn't convince you then please provide the exact numbers to compare. E.g. to tell how large your *partitions* are: `sudo gdisk -l /dev/sdb`; to tell how much space your target *filesystem* can provide: `POSIXLY_CORRECT=1 df /mountpoint/where/sdb2/is/mounted/`. Please [edit] the question and paste the outputs of these commands (after you [merge the accounts](https://superuser.com/help/merging-accounts), if necessary). I've seen your(?) proposed edits and I think you're still comparing wrong numbers. `64376668KiB` for `sdb1` is irrelevant; the *partition* is larger than that.

Comment: You're welcome. Full `dd` output will match the *partition* size, `df` operates on *filesystems*. `64376668KiB` is the space available on the *filesystem* within `sdb1`, the partition is *larger* for sure. Once again: what is the output of `gdisk -l /dev/sdb`? You can read the partition size from it, this is what matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every filesystem needs some space for metadata. Additionally `ext` family [reserves some space for `root` user](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/7950/108618) and it's 5% by default.

#### Example

In my Kubuntu I created a (sparse) file of 1GiB:

```
truncate -s 1G myfile
```

and made `ext3` filesystem within it. The command was plain

```
mkfs.ext3 myfile
```

This instantly allocated about 49MiB (~5% in this case) to the `myfile`. I could see that because the file was sparse and initially reported 0B usage on my real disk, then it grew. I assume this is where metadata lives.

I mounted the filesystem; `df -h` reported 976MiB of total space, but only 925MiB available. This means another ~5% wasn't available to me.

Then I filled up this space (after `cd` to the mountpoint) with

```
dd if=/dev/urandom of=placeholder
```

As a regular user I was able to take 925MiB only. The reported "disk" usage was then 100%. However, doing the same as a `root`, I could write 976MiB to the file. When the file grew over 925MiB the usage remained at 100%.

#### Conclusion

Comparing sizes of your partitions is wrong in this case; so is comparing the sizes of your filesystems. You should have checked the available space on the target *filesystem* (e.g. with `df`) and compare it to the size of the source *partition*.

---

#### EDIT:

To make it clear: your 66176851968 bytes are about 61.63 GiB. This is *not* larger than the source partition which is 62.5 GiB. The source *partition* was not fully read when the target *filesystem* got full.

In case you're not familiar with GB/GiB distinction, read [`man 7 units`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/units.7.html).

---

#### EDIT 2

Now we have all the actual numbers. Let's stick to the unit of `512B`, it's a common sector size.

- Your `sdb1` *partition* occupies `131074048-2048=131072000` units on the disk. Let's call this `P1`. This is from `gdisk` output.
- Your `sdb2` *partition* occupies `262889472-131074048=131815424` units on the disk. Let it be `P2`. This is also from `gdisk` output.
- Your *filesystem* inside `sdb1` can store files up to `128753336` units total. Let's call this number `F1`. This is from `df` output.
- Your *filesystem* inside `sdb2` can store up to `129484424` units. Let it be `F2`. This is also from `df` output.

The difference between `P1` and `F1`, as well as the difference between `P2` and `F2`, can be explained if you know there must be a room for metadata. This is mentioned earlier in this answer.

Your `dd` tried to copy the whole `sdb1` *partition*, i.e. `P1` of data, into a file that takes space provided by the *filesystem* inside `sdb2`, i.e. `F2` of available space.

**`P1` > `F2` – this is the final answer.** Your image file didn't grow larger than it should. It looks to me you expected its size to be `F1`. In fact the whole image would have a size of `P1` units.

`P2` and `F1` are irrelevant in this context.

Comment: Just found ths second EDIT  now. Earlier did my own investigation based on your earlier posts,which I posted as an answer to myself.  Sorry for that. And thank you very very much! Hope I wrote my answer correctly.

Comment: Hope I understood things right,  can you correct me if not?

Answer (score 0):

After that long discussion I realized what you mean.

We got to the point finally .
Well my question was kind of obscure initialy before I edited it. Really thank you!

I found this command to get the exact size of partitions in bytes:

root@sysresccd /root % parted /dev/sdb unit B p

Model: ATA WDC WD1600AAJS-0 (scsi)

Disk /dev/sdb: 160041885696B

Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B

Partition Table: msdos

Disk Flags:

Number  Start          End            Size          Type      File system     Flags

1      1048576B       67109912575B   67108864000B  primary   ext3            boot

2      67109912576B   134599409663B  67489497088B  primary   ext3

4      134600457216B  154668105727B  20067648512B  extended

5      134600458240B  150410887167B  15810428928B  logical   ext4

6      150411935744B  154668105727B  4256169984B   logical   linux-swap(v1)

3      154668105728B  160041009151B  5372903424B   primary   fat32           lba

So basicly I need to compare the real size of sdb1 (N1) in this list to the available space on sdb2 (N2) in this list.

But for that we use the POSIXLY_CORRECT=1 df command on the target (sdb2) filesystem which was: 129484424 512b-blocks in this case.

If we divide 67108864000B from sdb1 by 512 b = 131072000 512b-blocks .
 Or we can multiply  129484424*512 = 66296025088 Bytes.

So 66296025088 bytes (available space on sdb2) <  67108864000 bytes (raw size of sdb1).
 Clearly that sdb1 partition image  cannot fit into the available space on sdb2.
  And there is a space reserved for ROOT on sdb2 that also should be taken into account.

And as of my question about the image file larger than the partition I basicly compared the sdb1 filesystem size to the DD image instead of the raw partition size which shall be read in full by DD.
  Correct?
I can even approximate how much space I need for the operation to complete: 
 66,176,851,968 bytes was the size of the incompleted DD image so I compare it to the size of raw sdb1 partiton
66,176,851,968 = 66176851968 B < 67108864000 B  = smaller  by  932012032 Bytes = 888 MiB

But hey what is in there on empty partition ? Metadata and space reserved for root? So much space ???!!!!! Thank you very much!!

Good to know all this!!

Comment: Formal note: this site is not a forum, its Q&A. In an answer one shouldn't directly address anyone but the asker. You answer yourself (and it's OK to do so), not me; the answer should reflect this. Comments are for (reasonable) discussions.

Comment: I understand now, thanks! Thank you indeed for the help and the patience!

Comment: "So 66296025088 bytes (available space on `sdb2`) < 67108864000 bytes (raw size of `sdb1`). Clearly that `sdb1` partition image cannot fit into the available space on `sdb2`." Confirmed, these numbers seem correct to me. This is the main issue here and I'm glad we finally worked this out.

Comment: I`am glad too !